# How do I access Configuration in DbContext class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2 I'm trying to access Configuration in context class,I've done configurations like this:
in Program.cs:

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        ......
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
             {
                 IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

                 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
             })

           .Build();
```

in Startup.cs:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
```

I can access it in controllers like this:

```
public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
   {...}
```

but how do I access it in context class?
thanks

Comment: Do you mean a DbContext? Just add it as a constructor parameter, same as the controller. Also, your ConfigureAppConfiguration is not necessary, that's what the framework already does: https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L157-L158

Comment: Hi.tried by constructor:  public MyEntities(IConfiguration configuration)  {  } but all instances like this:  private MyEntities db = new MyEntities(); gives error in all controllers..no argument given..thanks

Comment: You have to also get MyEntities as a constructor parameter in the dependent class. You have to get it from DI always, you should not instantiate it yourself.

Comment: Hi,your answer is good,I also need to use MyEntities into a static class but got this error 'a static constructor must be parameterless'.thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your situation where you need IConfiguration in a DbContext class, you will have to add it to the constructor:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

But you also have to get `MyDbContext` from DI then. So a static class cannot receive it as a parameter. You will have to re-think how you are using the DbContext, and change it so that you get the context somewhere with access to DI, and pass that as an argument to any static methods that require it.